# Having trouble connecting access database to python using pyodbc- trying to read data

Tags: python, database, ms-access, pyodbc

Trying to connect access database to python so I can read it and eventually analyze it for certain things. But I can't connect to it and tried different approaches still getting the same error. I am using pyodbc.
Both python and access are 32bit. I am using windows 10 and the access is through MS office.

```
import pyodbc
connStr=(
    r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"C:\Users\jonat\Desktop\Eritrean.accdb;"
    )
cnxn=pyodbc.connect(connStr)
cursor=cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from MemberPayment')  
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

The error I've been getting

```
File "c:/Users/jonat/Desktop/pyth/prac.py", line 9, in <module>
    cnxn=pyodbc.connect(connStr)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
```

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: Nothing appears when I run     `pyodbc.drivers()`

Comment: Do `import struct` followed by `print("running as {0}-bit".format(struct.calcsize("P") * 8))` — what does it say?

Comment: running as 32-bit